# Managing user's global state on next.js application

Tags: node.js, next.js, server-side-rendering, react-state-management, global-state

I am coming from the world of **SPA's** and **REST/GraphQl API's**. Now I am building personal project with **Next.js** library for **SSR(Server Side Rendered) React App**.

Since I used **Redux** in all of my single page Apps, I'm now wondering how should I manage user state when every route user visits, a new link is loaded and the page has been refreshed.

I found some info about sessions and cookies, but neither of those are familiar to me. I looked at some online articles about using **Redux** with **Next.js** but it seems complicated.

Answer (score 11):

Let's simplify how Next works, browser sends a request to the server, Next renders on server side, returns an html, then, Next re-hydrate the page, and from now it behaves as SPA.

Next has an [example folder](https://github.com/zeit/next.js/tree/canary/examples) basically for every technology including `redux`.

Checkout the [redux example](https://github.com/zeit/next.js/tree/canary/examples/with-redux).

Answer (score 2):

If you're used to doing it in a route-based way, this may help understand:

1. the whole app (_app.js) is wrapped in the `Provider` for redux, so all `pages` and components in the app can access the `store`.
2. according to the docs:

   > ````
   > otherwise different user data can be mixed up. On the client side the
   > same store is used, even between page changes.```
   > ````
3. So your app will recreate the store on every request, but pass the `req`uest, the `url`, and possibly even the `res`ults (of the request) into the initial state of the `store`, so each page and component can utilize the `store` before rendering.
4. also checkout `getInitialProps` which will perform some sideEffect before the components on a page renders, and provide data to the page's props.

#### some resources:

- https://github.com/zeit/next.js/tree/canary/examples/with-redux
- https://medium.com/@bhavikbamania/a-beginner-guide-for-redux-with-next-js-4d018e1342b2